# How to make object accessible from non-google users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-storage, google-api-client

I am trying to use Google Cloud Storage service to store data.
And I succeed to upload data.

But I could not find how to share it for users who does not have google account.
And how can I get a unique URL of object in bucket?

Or else, how to download object by ruby-api-client?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Signed URLs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs) to grant access to a non-google user.